# Квадратные скобки в JS

Tags: javascript

Как употреблять квадратные скобки в именах переменных в `Javascript`, любые способы - главное чтоб имя переменной содержало `[`, я пытаюсь сделать - мне выдает `SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Comment: Примерно так же, как пробел и плюс.

Comment: Еще уточнение. Если не ошибаюсь, при использовании режима "strict mode" (use strict;) список зарезервированных слов и соответственно запрещенных к использованию в качестве имен (идентификаторов) переменных больше. Полный список см. в спецификации ECMA 5.1

Comment: @Semen Savenko А зачем Вам это потребовалось? Интересно же.

Comment: может посмотреть в строну массивов? там как раз получается с квадратными скобками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если имеется в виду ситуация `a['smth[]'] = 1;`, то тогда, собственно, вот и ответ. =)
Однако к такому свойству через точку не обратишься, только через квадратные скобки.
Квадратные скобки используются потому, что все объекты в JavaScript являются хэш-объектами. Почитать об этом можно [здесь](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/object/intro). Скорее всего, Вы хотите получить доступ к распарсенной переменной ответа, являющейся массивом (отсюда и квадратные скобки в наименовании переменной). Если проблема в этом, то попробуйте данные отдавать JSON'ом, а не обычными параметрами.

Answer (score 4):

Идентификаторы

> **Идентификатор** - это имя, под которым известна переменная или функция.
>   В JavaScript для идентификатора допустима любая комбинация букв, цифр,
>   знаков подчеркивания и знаков доллара. Единственным формальным
>   ограничением для идентификаторов является то, что они не должны
>   соответствовать никаким зарезервированным или ключевым словам
>   JavaScript и что первый символ не может быть цифрой.